# In Dropdown list onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>    
        function tab()
        {
            current=document.getElementById("test");
            next=document.getElementById("run");
            if(current.value!="-1")
            {
                next.focus()
            }
        }
    </script>
    <select id="test" onchange="tab()">
        <option value="-1">--select--</option>
        <option value="1" >TEST</option>
        <option value="2">RUN</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="run"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Definition: I have a dropdown which is having four values. If I change one value to another value in the dropdown it autotab to the textbox. As per my code, it is working fine.

But the issue is when I select 1st value in the dropdown then the autotab is working and again I select the same value from the dropdown (autotab is not working). I know that the problem is in the event. There is no change so the event won't fire. Please help me to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `onBlur()` .It will solve the problem

I think this is possible with html5

```
onselect
```

Comment: It not work in dropdown because as per my scenario while changing the dropdown value corresponding label and textbox will be show and after selecting the value from dropdown automatically it moves to text box. If we use onblur event calls only when we will click outside the dropdown event will fire.

Comment: In dropdown onselect event is not possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with id `run`, which is being referenced by:

```
document.getElementById("run");
```

You probably intended to write:

```
<input type="text" name="run" id="run"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onBlur()` instead of `onchange()`.

The `onBlur` event is fired when you have moved away from an object without necessarily having changed its value.

The `onChange` event is only called when you have changed the value of the field.

please have a lookinto this to know about [events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: It not work in dropdown because as per my scenario while changing the dropdown value corresponding label and textbox will be show and after selecting the value from dropdown automatically it moves to text box. If we use onblur event calls only when we will click outside the dropdown event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mouseup` & `keyup` event as a work around:

```js
var current = document.getElementById("test");
var next = document.getElementById("run");
var open = false; //drop-down closed

var watchOpen = function() {
  open = !open; //inverse flag to identify state of drop-down
};

var tab = function() {
  if (!open && current.value !== "-1") {
    next.focus();
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="test" onmouseup="watchOpen();tab();" onkeyup="watchOpen();tab();">
  <option value="-1">--select--</option>
  <option value="1">TEST</option>
  <option value="2">RUN</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="run" /><!-- replaced name with id -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="test" onchange="tab()">
      <option value="-1">--select--</option>
      <option value="1">TEST</option>
      <option value="2">RUN</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="run" id="run" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function tab() {
        current = document.getElementById("test");
        next = document.getElementById("run");
        if (current.value != "-1") {
          next.focus();
          next.value = current.options[current.selectedIndex].text;
        } else {
          next.value = "";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change in your code and you are good to go.

```
<select id="test" onchange="tab()" onblur="tab()">
        <option value="-1">--select--</option>
        <option value="1">TEST</option>
        <option value="2">RUN</option>
</select>
```

This will work.